# Tweepy, how to pull count integer and use it

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I trust all is well with everyone here. My apologies if this has been answered before, though I am trying to do the following.

```
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search_tweets,
    q = '"Hello"',
    lang = 'en',
    result_type = 'recent',
    count = 2
)
```

I want to match the number in count, to the number of json objects I will be iterating through.

```
for tweet in cursor.items():
    tweet_payload = json.dumps(tweet._json,indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

I have tried several different ways to write the data, though it would appear that the following does not work (currently is a single fire):

```
    with open("Tweet_Payload.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(tweet_payload)
        time.sleep(.25)
    outfile.close()
```

This is what it looks like put together.

```
import time
import tweepy
from tweepy import cursor
import Auth_Codes
import json

twitter_auth_keys = {
    "consumer_key"          : Auth_Codes.consumer_key,
    "consumer_secret"       : Auth_Codes.consumer_secret,
    "access_token"          : Auth_Codes.access_token,
    "access_token_secret"   : Auth_Codes.access_token_secret
}

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
    twitter_auth_keys["consumer_key"],
    twitter_auth_keys["consumer_secret"]
)

auth.set_access_token(
    twitter_auth_keys["access_token"],
    twitter_auth_keys["access_token_secret"]
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

cursor = tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search_tweets,
    q = '"Hello"',
    lang = 'en',
    result_type = 'recent',
    count = 2
)

for tweet in cursor.items():
    tweet_payload = json.dumps(tweet._json,indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    with open("Tweet_Payload.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(tweet_payload)
        time.sleep(.25)
    outfile.close()
```

Edit:
Using the suggestion by Mickael

also, the current code

```
tweet_payload = []
for tweet in cursor.items():
    tweet_payload.append(tweet._json)
    print(json.dumps(tweet_payload, indent=4,sort_keys=True))

    with open("Tweet_Payload.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(tweet_payload,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        time.sleep(.25)
```

Just loops, I am not sure why thats the case when the count is 10. I thought it would run just 1 call for 10 results or less, then end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the file with the write mode erases its previous data so, if you want to add each new tweet to the file, you should use the append mode instead.

As an alternative, you could also store all the tweets' json in a list and write them all at once. That should be more efficient and the list at the root of your json file will make it valid.

```py
json_tweets = []

for tweet in cursor.items():
    json_tweets.append(tweet._json)

with open("Tweet_Payload.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(json_tweets,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

On a side note, the `with` closes the file automatically, you don't need to do it.

Comment: Mickael.... Ya know... I totally forgot about the difference between append and writing. Excuse me while I kick a can down the street -.-

Follow up question. Will this allow me to filter the tweets data one by one as they come in? Theres a lot of extra stuff in the payload that I would like to filter out.

Comment: @NovemberFalls You're welcome! And well, I guess that the easiest solution would be to replace the` tweet._json` by the creation of an dictionary with the fields you want to keep. For example: `json_tweets.append({id: tweet.id, text: tweet.text})`